# notifyItemChanged() not working when called within setOnUtteranceProgressListener

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

**Edit**

I've created a demo project on `Github` showing the exact problem. [Git Project](https://github.com/Dan277/notifyItemChangedProblem).

---

I've written an expandable `recyclerView` in `Kotlin` Every row has a play button which uses `TextToSpeech`. The text of the play button should change to stop whilst its playing, then change back to play when it finishes.

When I call `notifyItemChanged` within `onStart` and `onDone` of `setOnUtteranceProgressListener`, `onBindViewHolder` is not called and the rows in the recyclerView will no longer expand and collapse correctly.

```
t1 = TextToSpeech(context, TextToSpeech.OnInitListener { status ->
    if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
        t1?.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(object : UtteranceProgressListener() {
            override fun onStart(utteranceId: String?) {
                recyclerView.adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)
            }

            override fun onStop(utteranceId: String?, interrupted: Boolean) {
                    super.onStop(utteranceId, interrupted)
                    onDone(utteranceId)
            }

            override fun onDone(utteranceId: String?) {
                val temp = position
                position = -1
                recyclerView.adapter.notifyItemChanged(temp)
            }

            override fun onError(utteranceId: String?) {}
//                    override fun onError(utteranceId: String?, errorCode: Int) {
//                        super.onError(utteranceId, errorCode)
//                    }
        })
    }
})
```

onBindViewHolder:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RabbanaDuasViewHolder, position: Int){
    if (Values.playingPos == position) {
        holder.cmdPlay.text = context.getString(R.string.stop_icon)
    }
    else {
        holder.cmdPlay.text = context.getString(R.string.play_icon)
    }
}
```

How can I call `notifyItemChanged(position)` from within `setOnUtteranceProgressListener` or what callback can I use so that notifyItemChanged only executes when it's safe to execute?

Comment: `Values.position` is a variable in a static object. I use that because I moved the `setOnUtteranceProgressListener` from the `adapter` to the `fragment` to see if that would solve the problem. I've not manually created any new threads, however it seems like the problem is still to do with thread safety, as it clearly seems unsafe to call `notifyItemChanged` from within `setOnUtteranceProgressListener`. I already confirmed `onStart` and `onDone` are being called correctly.

Comment: @acarlstein The text is already displayed so a deaf person could just read the text but they may need to click the row to expand and view the whole text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried to replicate your issue and I came to know that it is not working because methods of `UtteranceProgressListener` is not called on main thread and that's why `onBindViewHolder` method of the adapter is not called.

This worked for me and should work for you too:

Use `runOnUiThread{}` method to perform actions on `RecyclerView` like this:

```
t1.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(object : UtteranceProgressListener() {
    override fun onError(utteranceId: String?) {
    }

    override fun onStart(utteranceId: String?) {
        runOnUiThread {
            recyclerView.adapter?.notifyItemChanged(position)
        }
    }

    override fun onStop(utteranceId: String?, interrupted: Boolean) {
        super.onStop(utteranceId, interrupted)
        onDone(utteranceId)
    }

    override fun onDone(utteranceId: String?) {
        val temp = position
        position = -1
        runOnUiThread {
            recyclerView.adapter?.notifyItemChanged(temp)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem using `runOnUiThread` thanks to [Birju Vachhani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9199362/birju-vachhani).

For a full working demo of not just the problem I had, but how to correctly expand and collapse rows in a `RecyclerView` (no `onClick` events in `onBindViewHolder`) see my [Gitlab Demo Project](https://github.com/Dan277/notifyItemChangedProblem).